# Router.use requires middleware function but got object : node.js / express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am getting an error when calling my router from my routes directory whenever i try to initialize a route with app.use(). The error i am getting says Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object. I've read that this could be due to me not exporting the module correctly. However i am not sure what exactly is wrong with my code below. Im pretty sure the error is in how i have the controller architected. I've tried using module.exports instead but keep getting the error. What could i try to fix this?

Error:

```
Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/src/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/src/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
    at module.exports (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/src/routes/router.js:18:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/src/app.js:60:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at loader (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Desktop/personal/app/server/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My `route.js` file that contains all my route methods. In app.js: I use  `import router from  './routes/router';` then call this with: `router(app);`

```
import express from 'express'
import feed from '../controllers/feed.controller'
import file from '../controllers/file.controller'
import flight from '../controllers/flight.controller'

module.exports = function (app) {

  // Initializing route groups
  const apiRoutes = express.Router(),
    feedRoutes = express.Router(),
    fileRoutes = express.Router(),
    flightRoutes = express.Router(),
    indexRoutes = express.Router();

  //= ========================
  // Feed Routes
  //= ========================//

  apiRoutes.use('/feeds', feed);

  apiRoutes.use('/downloads', feed);

  // Find all feeds
  feedRoutes.get('/', feed.list_all_feeds);

  // Find one feed
  feedRoutes.get('/:id', feed.list_one_feed);

  // Find one Audience
  feedRoutes.get('/:id/:audienceId', feed.list_one_feed_audience);

  // Download one Feed
  feedRoutes.get('/:id/download', feed.download_one_feed);

  //= ========================
  // File Routes
  //= ========================//

  apiRoutes.use('/files', file);

  // Find all files
  fileRoutes.get('/', file.list_all_files);

  // Find one file
  fileRoutes.get('/:id', file.list_one_file);

  //= ========================
  // Flight Routes
  //= ========================//

  apiRoutes.use('/flights', flight);

  // Find all flights
  flightRoutes.get('/', flight.list_all_flights);

  // Find one flight
  flightRoutes.get('/:id', flight.list_one_flight);

  //= ========================
  // Index Routes
  //= ========================//

  // Set Main index Route
  apiRoutes.use('/',
    indexRoutes.get('/', function(req, res, next) { res.render('index', { title: 'Express', layout: 'layout.hbs' }) })
  );

  // Set url for API group routes
  app.use('/', apiRoutes);
}
```

An example of one of my controllers. (all contain the same pattern):

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
// models
import Flight from '../models/flight.model'

exports.list_all_flights = function(req, res) {
  Flight.find({})
  .exec(function(err, dbflights){
    if(err) {
      res.send('error has occured in router');
    } else {
      console.log('successful get from routes/flights.js ...');
      res.json(dbflights);
    }
  });
};

exports.list_one_flight = function(req, res) {
  Flight.findOne({'name': req.params.id})
  .exec(function(err, dbflights){
    if(err){
      res.send('get error has occured in routes/feeds.js');
    } else {
      res.json(dbflights);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: `apiRoutes.use('/files', file);` why? `file` is an object, you cant mount it as a middleware.

Comment: Trying to set file routes as subgroup/middleware to apiRoutes @JonasW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mounting the objects, might just mount the routes instead? So replace:

```
 apiRoutes.use('/feeds', feed);
```

with:

```
 apiRoutes.use('/feeds', feedRoutes);
```